# Iteration over a struct vector

Tags: rust

I have a struct that has a vector of another struct type.

```
struct Element {
    val: String,
}

struct Collection {
    elements: Vec<Element>,
}

impl Collection {
    fn process(&mut self) {
        for entry in &self.elements.iter_mut() {
            entry.val = "New value".to_string();
            println!("{}", entry.val);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let e1 = Element {
        val: "My first entry".to_string(),
    };
    let e2 = Element {
        val: "My second entry".to_string(),
    };
    let mut c = Collection { elements: vec![] };
    c.elements.push(e1);
    c.elements.push(e2);
    c.process();
}
```

When I try to iterate over it, I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&std::slice::IterMut<'_, Element>: std::iter::Iterator` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:11:22
   |
11 |         for entry in &self.elements.iter_mut() {
   |                      -^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                      |
   |                      `&std::slice::IterMut<'_, Element>` is not an iterator; maybe try calling `.iter()` or a similar method
   |                      help: consider removing 1 leading `&`-references
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for `&std::slice::IterMut<'_, Element>`
   = note: required by `std::iter::IntoIterator::into_iter`
```

I think this is because `&self.elements` is really a reference. Using `self.elements` would work, but I was hoping to modify the actual objects rather than a copy.

What would be a proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Switch to this:

```
for entry in self.elements.iter_mut() { /* ... */ }
```

Or more idiomatically:

```
for entry in &mut self.elements { /* ... */ }
```

`IterMut` contains a *reference* to the items in the vector (and thus will change the vector items directly), but it is itself an object on the stack that will be changed as the iteration progresses.

> ```
> the trait bound `&std::slice::IterMut<'_, Element>: std::iter::Iterator` is not satisfied
> ```

This is saying that you've got an `IterMut` by reference. That is, the precedence is different from what you think it is:

```
&self.elements.iter_mut() 
&(self.elements.iter_mut()) // Is this
(&self.elements).iter_mut() // Not this
```

However, we'd have to do something like this:

```
(&mut self.elements).iter_mut()
```

because `iter_mut` needs a mutable reference as the receiver. Rust understands that and lets us just do the straightforward version and appropriately pass the mutability around:

```
self.elements.iter_mut()
```